# What is the recommended way to track document changes in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Let's say I have a `employees` collection where I have one document per employee and I want to keep record of all changes that were made to a single employee doc. I was thinking of the following approach:-

1. Have a `pendingEmployeeWrites` collection where client is
   only allowed to create documents. Each doc here will have an
   `employeeId` field (this id is generated on client side for new employees).
2. Cloud function will be invoked whenever such a doc is created and then it validates the data. If valid, the `employeeId` doc in `employees` collection is overwritten with this data. Otherwise the `pendingEmployeeWrites` doc is updated to set `isFailed` as `true`. Client app is only allowed to read from `employees` collection.

Keeping `pendingEmployeeWrites` as a flat collection instead of a sub-collection allows me to pull all changes made by a user as well as all changes for a particular document. Does this approach make sense or is there a better approach that I should consider?

Comment: Reasonable approach. Another way to do it would be to use transactions to write to both the document and some kind of "audit log" collection and use security rules to ensure that both are written simultaneously.